# How to trace a method call to its source code in a node js npm module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, npm, module

I want to be able to trace back methods from a node module back to their main files in the same order as they are working.

for example let's take mongoose module:

how to know what's happening inside `Model.find().exec();`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this in a generic way since functions can be dynamically generated (e.g. inside a node [`vm.Script`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/vm.html#vm_class_vm_script)) for example and thus may not have a real filename to point to.

You are probably better off just manually diving into the source code and doing a little detective work.

Comment: been trying that for a while